# KeyError "id" Python: Why isn't the key in the dictionary?

Tags: python

I wanted to know why this error occurs. I know the key is not in the dictionary but how come? Line 94 is labeled in the code below.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 154, in 
>       cp.add_song_to_playlist()
>
> File "", line 127, in add_song_to_playlist
>       playlist_id = self.create_playlist()
>        File "", line 94, in create_playlist
>       return response_json["id"] KeyError: 'id'

```
    import json
    import os

    import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
    import googleapiclient.discovery
    import googleapiclient.errors
    import requests
    import youtube_dl

    from exceptions import ResponseException
    from secrets import spotify_token, spotify_user_id


class CreatePlaylist:
def __init__(self):
    self.youtube_client = self.get_youtube_client()
    self.all_song_info = {}

def get_youtube_client(self):
    """ Log Into Youtube, Copied from Youtube Data API """
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    client_secrets_file = "client_secret.json"

    # Get credentials and create an API client
    scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"]
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()

    # from the Youtube DATA API
    youtube_client = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

    return youtube_client

def get_liked_videos(self):
    """Grab Our Liked Videos & Create A Dictionary Of Important Song Information"""
    request = self.youtube_client.videos().list(
        part="snippet,contentDetails,statistics",
        myRating="like"
    )
    response = request.execute()

    # collect each video and get important information
    for item in response["items"]:
        video_title = item["snippet"]["title"]
        youtube_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={}".format(
            item["id"])

        # use youtube_dl to collect the song name & artist name
        video = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({}).extract_info(
            youtube_url, download=False)
        song_name = video["track"]
        artist = video["artist"]

        if song_name is not None and artist is not None:
            # save all important info and skip any missing song and artist
            self.all_song_info[video_title] = {
                "youtube_url": youtube_url,
                "song_name": song_name,
                "artist": artist,

                # add the uri, easy to get song to put into playlist
                "spotify_uri": self.get_spotify_uri(song_name, artist)

            }

def create_playlist(self):
    """Create A New Playlist"""
    request_body = json.dumps({
        "name": "Youtube Liked Vids",
        "description": "All Liked Youtube Videos",
        "public": True
    })

    query = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/{}/playlists".format(
        spotify_user_id)
    response = requests.post(
        query,
        data=request_body,
        headers={
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(spotify_token)
        }
    )
    response_json = response.json()

    # playlist id
    try:
        response_json = response.json()
    except Exception:
        return None
    return response_json.get('id', None)


def get_spotify_uri(self, song_name, artist):
    """Search For the Song"""
    query = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=track%3A{}+artist%3A{}&type=track&offset=0&limit=20".format(
        song_name,
        artist
    )
    response = requests.get(
        query,
        headers={
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(spotify_token)
        }
    )
    response_json = response.json()
    songs = response_json["tracks"]["items"]

    # only use the first song
    uri = songs[0]["uri"]

    return uri

def add_song_to_playlist(self):
    """Add all liked songs into a new Spotify playlist"""
    # populate dictionary with our liked songs
    self.get_liked_videos()

    # collect all of uri
    uris = [info["spotify_uri"]
            for song, info in self.all_song_info.items()]

    # create a new playlist
    playlist_id = self.create_playlist()

    # add all songs into new playlist
    request_data = json.dumps(uris)

    query = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/{}/tracks".format(
        playlist_id)

    response = requests.post(
        query,
        data=request_data,
        headers={
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(spotify_token)
        }
    )

    # check for valid response status
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise ResponseException(response.status_code)

    response_json = response.json()
    return response_json


if __name__ == '__main__':
  cp = CreatePlaylist()
  cp.add_song_to_playlist()
```

Comment: Have you looked at what the response JSON actually looks like? (i.e. have you done this manually and ensured that it works exactly like what you're doing in code). You'll have to check what the API is giving you and adjust your code to accommodate that - in this case it seems to not be giving you an `"id"` key.

Comment: format correctly your answer. What is the line you add in the middle of your code `line 94: return response_json["id"]` ?

Comment: Sorry, it should be # playlist id
  return response_json["id"]

Comment: Learn to use a debugger!  Then you can step through your code and see what is **actually** in your dictionary.

Comment: I debugged response.json and it says The access token has expired. How do I refresh this?

Answer (score 2):

This exception occurs when you try to get undefined keys value with [] from dict. To gently handle this try to use .get('id', None).

```
try:
    response_json = response.json()
except Exception:
    return None
return response_json.get('id', None)
```

it will return None if there is no value for the key 'id'.
You can replace None with any fallback value.

Comment: This gives me TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable along with the same errors I had above.

Comment: Then try handle response for exception.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 158, in <module>
    cp.add_song_to_playlist()
  File "", line 150, in add_song_to_playlist
    raise ResponseException(response.status_code)
exceptions.ResponseException: Response gave status code 401

Process finished with exit code 1

This error comes out now. Perhaps I am not getting ID's from that code